# iPhone alert view exclude a view controller

Tags: iphone, uialertview

i have a project with many vie controller, in one of these i create and show a view alert. it's possible show alert in every view exclude one?

I need this because if you are in the alarm view controller you don't need to see the alert when alarm ring

i try this but not works!

```
// ALERT NOTIFICATION 
if (!self.timerViewController) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Piccole Ricette" message:@"READY" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Make sure you implement the UIAlertView Delegate

Comment: what doesn't work? if the if statement isn't there does it fire and everything correctly?

Comment: Yeah i implement UIAlertViewDelegate but the alert is show in very view.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can test whether a ViewController 's view is visible by testing the view's `window` property.  If the view is not visible the window property will be `nil`.  So perhaps you can do something like this:

```
if (!self.timerViewController.view.window) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Piccole Ricette" message:@"READY" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```